# How to create a non-overlapping stacked bar graph?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am making a stacked bar graph for analysis, it is working properly except for Values are getting overlapped
[image]

in the above fiure everything is working properly, except for the **order value** is overlapping **supply value** but whereas i want supply to stack over order

here is the code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

ind = np.arange(N)    
width = 0.3 

p1 = plt.bar(ind, order, width, color='yellow')
p2 = plt.bar(ind, supply, width, color='red', bottom=order)
p3 = plt.bar(ind, feedback, width, color='green', bottom=supply)

plt.xlabel('date')
plt.title('hello')
plt.yticks(np.arange(0,24000,6000))
plt.legend((p1[0], p2[0], p3[0]), ('order', 'supply', 'feedback'))

plt.show()
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].

Comment: It's a little unclear what you're asking. What is your expected behavior and what are you getting?

Comment: @milesper the expexted behaviour is th **red color** section should stack over **yellow color** section, which is not happening. Here according to this diagram both **red color and yellow color** start from 0, which is not the expected behaviour

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your problem you want to stack

order(yellow)-->supply(red)-->feedback(green) vertically

You can replace line

```
p3 = plt.bar(ind, feedback, width, color='green', bottom=supply)
```

with

```
p3 = plt.bar(ind, feedback, width, color='green',bottom=[order[j] +supply[j] for j in range(len(order))])
```

Here is similar working example

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

ind = np.arange(5)    
width = 0.3 
order=[2,3,1,5,4]
supply=[3,4,2,6,5]
feedback=[1,1,1,1,1]

p1 = plt.bar(ind, order,width, color='yellow')
p2 = plt.bar(ind, supply, width, color='red',bottom=order)
p3 = plt.bar(ind, feedback, width, color='green',bottom=[order[j] +supply[j] for j in range(len(order))])

plt.xlabel('date')
plt.title('hello')
plt.legend((p1[0], p2[0], p3[0]), ('order', 'supply', 'feedback'))

plt.show()
```

Comment: Is the code compiling? If yes, can you assign different widths to three bars and post the output figure..

Comment: it is compiling but the result is blank

Comment: Do you see matplotlib window?

Comment: yes i did..but there was no plot except for some peak dashes instead of the bar graph

Answer (score 0):

I would iterate over the data and keep a running tab of the "bottom" list. For example:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

ind = np.arange(5)
order = [1,2,3,1,1]
supply = [2,2,2,4,3]
feedback = [1,2,5,6,7]
width = 0.5
bottom = [0 for x in ind]
data = [order,supply,feedback]
colors = ["yellow","red","green"]
for color,item in zip(colors,data):
    plt.bar(ind,item,width,color=color,bottom=bottom)
    bottom = [a+b for a,b in zip(bottom,item)]

plt.show()
```

For 3 things a for loop is probably overkill, but I think you get the idea.